# Test::unit and Rubymine "No tests were found"

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rubymine, testunit

I'm a newbie in Ruby and I try to use the test::unit framework with the RubyMine IDE (3.1.1).

I don't understand the note about test::unit here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/test-unit-special-note.html

Specially this instruction: "Include test-unit gem in your Gemfile." I use gem install "test-unit" and attach it to my project but I still got 0 tests and the error message "No tests were found"

Comment: For single tests also see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-30693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have a `Gemfile` in your project root which contains:

```
gem 'test-unit'
```

Comment: Thanks! I add the file, install the bundler gem and run the cmd bundler install. I got an error with one of my requires (httparty) and added it in my gemfile too. Now I got no error but 0 tests run :(

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason that can cause some scenario not to be recognized. If there is an scenario with the same name in other feature, it may cause your scenario not to be detected.